# What force causes a change in a domain's direction?

Tags: quantum-spin, material-science, magnetic-moment, ferromagnetism

I have read that to make a material paramagnetic you can place a strong magnet next to it. How does this magnet align the domains inside the other material?

Comment: Do you understand that the atoms or molecules of the magnetizable material are little magnetic dipoles?

Comment: Hi Lalitha. Paramagnetic materials do not have domains. Only ferromagnets have domains. Did you mean that placing a powerful magnet next to a ferromagnetic material causes the domains in the ferromagnetic material to align and produce a permanent magnetic field?

Answer (score 0):

In condensed matter physics, "paramagnet" refers to the nonmagnetic phase of a magnetic material. Basically, in a material capable of magnetically ordering (e.g., ferromagnets), the paramagnetic phase is the phase that has no magnetic order. Now, the term "paramagnet" has a slightly different definition in chemistry, but the principles are quite similar to what I stated above, and the physics I will describe is the same.

Conventional phases of matter are classified by the symmetries they respect, and those they break spontaneously. For example, liquids and gases have continuous translation symmetry: Every point is indistinguishable from every other (on average). A solid, however, spontaneously breaks this continuous symmetry by forming a crystalline lattice. Only *certain* points (corresponding to the positions of atoms on the lattice, e.g.) are equivalent to each other. The solid is the "ordered" phase (which spontaneously breaks translation symmetry) and the liquid is the "disordered" phase (which respects the symmetry).

The symmetry that magnets break corresponds to *orientation*. Solids generally have no preferred orientation—in other words, they have no "North Pole". But *ferro*magnets do have a preferred orientation, and correspondingly, they spontaneously break rotational symmetry. The ferromagnetic phase is like the solid, and the paramagnetic phase (which respects rotation symmetry) is like the liquid.

I will assume that you meant to ask about putting a strong magnet next to a paramagnetic material to induce domains (and possibly cause a phase transition to a ferromagnet). But you cannot "make" a material paramagnetic. In the condensed matter sense, paramagnetism is simply one of several phases of matter a given material can realize, depending on various parameters. In the chemistry sense, paramagnetism is simply the presence of little electrons with internal magnetic moments, which is a property of basically every material.

Magnetic ordering is due to alignment of the local electrons' magnetic moments. You can think of each electron as a mini bar magnet with a North and South pole, and in a ferromagnet, they like to align. This mechanism is the same as the one that causes two macroscopic ferromagnets to align, and the one that creates domains inside a paramagnet as field strength is increased, eventually causing a phase transition to a ferromagnet (in some cases).

The way the alignment happens is that it is energetically favorable for all the local spins (of the material's electrons) to "point" in the same direction.

The prefix "para" means "next to" (i.e. "closely related to"): The paramagnet is the nonmagnetic (disordered) phase of a material that is *capable* of magnetic order (for example, ferromagnetism). Generally speaking, there are two parameters that determine the phase diagram, and thereby the transition between the ordered ferromagnet and disordered paramagnet: temperature $T$ and applied magnetic field $h$.

At $T=0$, there are two ground states: all spins pointing up  and all spins pointing down. The direction they point defines the North pole. Now, at higher temperatures, we can flip spins (due to the intrinsic dynamics and using thermal energy from the environment to pay the "cost" for misalignment). At very high temperatures, there are just too many flipped spins and the material becomes a paramagnet.

However, an applied field also introduces an energetic penalty. Basically, spins will prefer to align with the field (in the same way they prefer to align with each other). So there is some competition between the field strength $h$ and temperature $T$ (I don't know the formula, but other people do!).

But this is only in the setting in which "paramagnet" refers to the nonmagnetized phase of a material that is capable of ferromagnetism. But this is not always the case for a given paramagnet (some may have an *anti*ferromagnet for the ordered phase, which you won't perceive as magnetically ordered because basically spins like to anti align, so the net magnetic moment is zero). But for ferromagnetic materials, my answer above holds.

Anyway, the "force" in question is the magnetic force. It causes magnetic dipoles (such as the electrons in materials) to prefer to align with one another. In nonmagnetic materials, this interaction is too small compared to other interactions for magnetic domains to form. But it's just magnetism...you can think of electrons as little bar magnets with a north and south pole. Another way to visualize is by looking at experiments using magnets and a bunch of iron filaments, and you can watch them physically align with the local field.

Comment: I think what you say about "paramagnetic" here is not strictly correct

Comment: ok...which part is incorrect? What would the correct statement be?

Comment: A quick search produced this: "Paramagnetic materials are materials that tend to get weakly magnetized in the direction of the magnetizing field when placed in a magnetic field. Paramagnetic materials have a permanent dipole moment or permanent magnetic moment."

Comment: Also i think the "para" prefix in this case means "closely related to"

Comment: That seems consistent with what I wrote? The permanent moments are the electrons, and the weak magnetization is for small applied fields. A paramagnet can become ferromagnetic with very strong fields in certain materials, which I focused on. My phrasing may have disguised these points, since I come from condensed matter (rather than chemistry), where we don't talk about paramagnetism in materials with no other magnetic phases. The chemistry definition of paramagnetism to us is equivalent to saying "there be electrons".